# Styles.Render not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5

using the usual syntax

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="css-main" href="~/assets/css/site.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="css-main" href="~/assets/css/bluetheme.css">
```

everything works as it should.
In order to clean that up a bit, I wanted to use Style.Render

```
@Styles.Render("~/assets/css")
```

which I believe includes all the css files in that folder.

But the styles are not working on the page. What am I doing wrong?

Update: well there were two typos in my BundleConfig but they are now fixed and the style s still dont work

Here is my bundle config

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/assets/css").Include(
             "~/assets/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/assets/site.css",
                   "~/assets/bluetheme.css"
            ));
    }
```

and this is in the head section of my layout view

```
 @Styles.Render("~/assets/css")
```

Comment: Have you added your bundleConfig.cs to you global.asax file?

Comment: Can you give more info? What environment? Is your config setup to enable bundling? Where are you putting the @Styles.Render()?

Comment: yes, but thats where the problem was...two typos

Comment: @Pete, and how is it a duplicate, if the issues are different, the code is correct and the styling doesnt work?

Comment: @dinotom, at the time with the info provided when it was voted to close, it was a duplicate as the other question gives **all** the steps for you to get bundling to work.  Now you have edited, I still see no reason to reopen it